# Spring Form binding to List<Integer> not working when upgraded to Java 8

Tags: spring-mvc, java-8

We are upgrading our Spring MVC system to Java 8 compiled from Java 6 compiled. During runtime, we are loading a form object into List which when iterated throws java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
 cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

The same code was working fine in our production environment which is compiled with Java 6.

Below is the excerpt from our code base.

### JSP

```
<div class="row">
        <span class="lbl"> <b>Menus</b>: </span>
        <span class="formw">
            <form:select path="selectedMenuIdList" multiple="true" id="selectedMenuIdList" size="5">
                <c:forEach items="${menus}" var="topLevelMenu">
                    <form:option value="${topLevelMenu.menuId}">-<c:out value="${topLevelMenu.menuTitle}"/></form:option>
                    <c:forEach items="${topLevelMenu.childList}" var="subMenu"><form:option value="${subMenu.menuId}">---<c:out value="${subMenu.menuTitle}"/></form:option></c:forEach>
                </c:forEach>
            </form:select>
        </span>
    </div>
```

### Controller

I have not added the complete method. But this is what it is exactly doing.

```
 protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ManageUserCommand command, BindException errors) throws Exception
    {
        List<Integer> selectedMenuIdList = command.getSelectedMenuIdList();
        for (Integer menu : selectedMenuIdList){//exception thrown here 
        userMenu.setMenuId(menuId);
        userMenuDao.save(userMenu);
     }
    }
```

when I re-write the code as below it works.

```
Iterator<Integer> i = selectedMenuIdList.iterator();
 while(i.hasNext()){
    String temp = String.valueOf(i.next());
    Integer menuId = Integer.parseInt(temp);
    userMenu.setMenuId(menuId);
    userMenuDao.save(userMenu);
 }
```

Please clarify what is going wrong with using java 8 since we cannot re-write all the code as above to make it work with java 8.

Comment: Show the entire controller method (*especially the arguments*)

Comment: I highly doubt it has something to do with java version. Probably it has something to do with upgrading your version of Spring MVC.